# Best practices for visual studio XML documentation of subclasses?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, xml-documentation

Programming in VS 2013 C++ and our doc standards call for XML documentation, in part so the comments appear in IntelliSense. My problem is that IntelliSense doesn't inherit documentation from base classes, so if I have something like this:

```
class Base {
public:
    Base() {}
    /// <summary> Really detailed and insightful comments </summary>
    virtual void method() = 0;
};

class Derived : public Base {
    Derived() {}
    void method() override {}
}
```

Typing

```
Base b;
b.method();   <- Gives nice IntelliSense tips
Derived d;
d.method();      <- Just shows +1 Override
```

I could copy-and-paste the comments, but really don't want to break the DRY principle. I've search and ReFactor and other tools can help sync comments, but our company's frugal, so not an option at the moment. Any out-of-the-box or free
  suggestions? My thought is to add the line

```
/// <summary> see base class for documentation </summary>
```

above overridden methods but would prefer something that would show the IntelliSense tips in the base class.

Comment: This would be a nice feature. I was already looking for something like this a lot of times in the past. Never found anything though. :(

Comment: Thanks Grega. So what did you adopt as a best practice? Did you cut-and-paste, add a "See base class" comment, or maybe something else?

Comment: If the comment includes some really important notes, then I copy-and-paste it. But usually I just add the "See base class" comment. Sadly, I don't see any other alternative ...